# Is there an easier way to prove this differentiation?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

> Given that 
>   $$\begin{aligned}
> &x=r\cos(\theta),\\
> &y=r\sin(\theta),\\
> & \qquad \text{and}\\
> &x^2+y^2=r^2
> \end{aligned}$$
>   Show that $\partial_y(\theta)=\cos(\theta)/r.$

I tried the following:

Since $$\partial_\theta(y)=\partial_\theta(r)\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)$$
then 
$$\partial_\theta(r)=\frac{\partial_\theta(y)-r\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$
Using $x^2+y^2=r^2:$
$$\partial_y\left( x^2+y^2\right)=\partial_\theta (r^2)\cdot\partial_y(\theta)\implies 2y=2r\,\partial_\theta (r)\cdot\partial_y(\theta)$$
Substituting and simplifying
$$1=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot\frac{\partial_\theta(y)-r\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot\partial_y(\theta)\implies\partial_y(\theta)\cdot\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)}-1$$
simplifying again
$$\partial_y(\theta)=\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}$$

Is there a quicker way to prove this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\theta=\arctan (\frac {y}{x}) +k\pi$$

$$\implies \;\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial y}=\frac {1}{x}\frac {1}{1+(\frac {y}{x})^2} $$
$$=\frac {x}{r^2} $$
$$=\frac {\cos (\theta)}{r}$$

Comment: I did not even notice this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial x}{\partial r}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial r}\\
\frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial r}{\partial x}&\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial x}\\
\frac {\partial r}{\partial y}&\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial x}{\partial r}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial r}\\
\frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
 \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta&-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\\
\sin\theta&\frac {\cos\theta}{r}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I don't understand this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The Jacobian matrix is a way to represent the partial derivatives of function from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$  In this case $F(r,\theta) = x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta) = r\cos\theta, r\sin \theta$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ and the inverse function theorem says that if $F$ has an inverse,  the Jacobian matrix of the inverse function is the inverse of the Jacobian of the function.

Comment: I did not know about this. Thank you